# All sprites added to CCNode are clumped in one point

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccnode

I used `Hearts1.CCPositionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized` for my CCNode, Hearts1.
For all sprites inside the node, I also used `CCPositionTypeNormalized`

None of my sprites seem to move around, they just stack on top of each other in the same point. Do I need to change the `ContentSize` of the node to match the viewSize?

Answer (score 1):

```
ScreenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
ScreenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
heart1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight);
```

This prevents all the sprites from being clumped in one point.